# py2neo ogm incoming related is None, why?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm in trouble when i want to get incoming relation from a node with py2neo ogm. Here an exemple:

```
class A1(GraphObject):
    rFrom = RelatedFrom("A2", "A2")

class A2(GraphObject):
    rTo = RelatedTo("A1", "A1")

a1 = A1()
a2 = A2()
a2.rTo.add(a1)

GRAPH.push(a2)

n_a1 =  list(A1.select(GRAPH))[0]
n_a2 =  list(A2.select(GRAPH))[0]

print list(n_a1.rFrom)
print list(n_a2.rTo)

[]
[<A1 __id__=1006>]
```

So, I don't understand how to get incoming relation with ogm mapping. 
Is it a bug ? or me ? 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, relation name must be the same, Related attributs is not enougth.

```
class A1(GraphObject):
    rFrom = RelatedFrom("A2", "LINK")

class A2(GraphObject):
    rTo = RelatedTo("A1", "LINK")

a1 = A1()
a2 = A2()
a2.rTo.add(a1)

GRAPH.push(a2)

n_a1 =  list(A1.select(GRAPH))[0]
n_a2 =  list(A2.select(GRAPH))[0]

print list(n_a1.rFrom)
print list(n_a2.rTo)

[<A2 __id__=1007>]
[<A1 __id__=1006>]
```